# Repeat indecies of an array sequentially until it matches specified value

Tags: php, arrays

I am attempting to write a function that will cycle through an array and perform a task based on its value.

For example:

```
foreach ($content as $i => $c) {
    cycle(array('<div class="row">', '', ''), $i)
    $content;
    cycle(array('', '', '</div>'), $i)
}
```

The function:

```
function cycle($cycles, $i) {
    if ($cycles[$i] !== '') {
       echo $cycles[$i];
    }
}
```

This works fine if the length (count) of the array I am passing into `cycle()` matches the number of forloop iterations where I am calling the function.  However, if the number of iterations is greater obviously I get errors.

Some of you may have guessed that I am trying to wrap content with a `<div class="row"></div>` at the specified number of iterations or cycles.  I do not want to use modulo.

I want the `cycle()` function to ignore empty values and only output it's value if it is not an empty string or `null`.

Ideally, if my array is too short, I want to keep repeating its own indices starting at 0 until it's indices count matches `$i`.

So if i had an array such as `$arr = array(a,b,c,d);` amd and pass it to my `cycle($arr)` function and this runs in a forloop 7 times, I want to somehow fill in the array thusly: `array(a,b,c,d,a,b,c)` . so I can output the required number of opening and closing divs.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: can you provide example $content array and example desired output string (html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (working [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/46a59b46d40a93708c9ff64104dbfd64b4ac1905))

```
function cycle($cycles, $i) {
    $j=$i%count($cycles);
    if ($cycles[$j] !== '') {
       echo $cycles[$j];
    }
}
```